# Call a mocha test file from node js file and then return the output of mocha file to the calling node js to continue its exectuion

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have two files say 
file 1 : index.js ( run using node index )
file 2 : test.js  ( run using mocha test )

First I run index.js 
index.js must call test.js during its execution
test.js must return a particular value back to index.js to continue index.js execution.

All these must happen in single call...

Any inputs?

Comment: You can run Mocha [programmatically](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically), but I don't see how you can get the test file to return a particular value other than the number of failures.

Comment: I am using webdriver io to navigate to a page and getValue of an element. And the value needs to be return back..